# ALSA - Cannot obtain info for CTL elem

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, alsa, portaudio, pyttsx

I'm trying to add text to speech to the AI that i'm currently building using pyttsx and portaudio and I cannot get the thing to speak

I've installed pyttsx3, portaudio, gtts, espeak and it just returns the below error.
I've had a look at this question: [Portaudio and ALSA: "Cannot obtain info for CTL elem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552562/portaudio-and-alsa-cannot-obtain-info-for-ctl-elem)
but it is a little different in the sense that he gets something out of the speaker, but i get nothing.

This is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Hello, My name is MARTIN')
engine.runAndWait()
```

This is my error message:

```
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'AC97 2ch->4ch Copy Switch',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'AC97 2ch->4ch Copy Switch',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (PCM,'IEC958 Playback PCM Stream',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (PCM,'IEC958 Playback PCM Stream',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:547:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (PCM,'IEC958 Playback PCM Stream',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
```

Comment: PortAudio searches for things (that are not actually there) by trying to access them, and does not hide the resulting error messages. There is no information about your actual problem.